# PSQL select either a or b in order but not both a and b if both a and b exists

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, logical-operators

I have a PSQL table

```
+--------+------+------+------+
|  Col1  | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+--------+------+------+------+
|    001 | 00A  | 00B  | 001  |
| 001001 | 00A  | 00B  | 001  |
|    002 | 00X  | 00Y  | 002  |
| 002002 | 00X  | 00Y  | 002  |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

I have the following PSQL query:

```
select *
from my_table
where (Col1 = '001' or Col4 = '001')
  and Col2 = '00A'
order by Col3 asc;
```

I get the first two rows.

Here what happens is that it matches both conditions for `OR` condition. I need to match **only one of** the `or` conditions. That is if first condition (`Col1='001001'`) is true then **do not evaluate** the next condition.
I need to select only the 2nd row (`| 001001 | 00A  | 00B  | 001  |`)

I have build another query using `EXCEPT`

```
select *
from my_table
where (Col1 = '001' or Col4 = '001')
  and Col2 = '00A'
    except (select *
            from my_table
            where Col1 != '001'
              and Col2 = '00A')
order by Col3 asc
limit 1;
```

I would like to know if there is any other elegant queries for this job?

Comment: Use Case condition

Comment: @NidhinDavid . . . I'm really confused.  The condition `Col1='001001'` isn't in your query.  Even if you fix that, I'm still pretty confused on what you want.  Do you always want exactly one row?  What if more rows match your condition?

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you want?

```
select *
from my_table
where (Col1 = '001' and Col2 != '00A')
    or ((Col1 is null or Col1 = '') and Col4 = '001' and Col2 = '00A')
order by Col3 asc;
```

Comment: nope. If both col1 and col4 exists then it fetches both. I only want col1 if it exists. only if col1 doesnot exists it should check col4. col2 must exists in all cases

Comment: By "exists" you mean not null? Maybe would help to add an example case where you want a row where column one is "001" and a case that matches your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is confusing as you say `col1 = '001001'` in one place and use `001` in the query. But I presume you want to use a hierarchy of comparison and return the one with the highest per each group ( `col2,col3,col4`) . Use `DISTINCT ON`. Change the condition in whichever way you like to return the appropriate row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col2, col3, col4) * 
  FROM     my_table WHERE  col2 = '00A' 
ORDER  BY col2, 
          col3, 
          col4, 
          CASE 
            WHEN col1 = '001001' THEN 1 
            WHEN col4 = '001'    THEN 2 
          END;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7c0433f9bb3fe9fa9dc7818fc6111691)